# Restrict : XmlSerializer() to removed closing tag from XML in nodejs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, xml, scripting

Closing tag is automatically removed from XML when I try to serialize XML to a string.

```
let serializedXmlContent = new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(doc);
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not clear what you're asking. Can you provide an example of what the output is, and what you'd like it to be?

Comment: output Showing: <States><State Code="AR" Show="true"/><States> and it should be like this(expected one): <States><State Code="AR" Show="true"></State><States>